# Assigning Virtual Attribute in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, virtual-attribute

I'm attempting to understand the difference between these two ways of assigning virtual attributes in Rails 4. One of them causes a "stack level too deep" and one of them works fine. I'm attempting to use the new ActiveRecord array field by parsing a textfield and splitting it by commas to create a tag field. The working code is as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def tags=(s)
    self[:tags] = s.split(/,\s+/)
  end
end
```

However, when I change this to assign the tag field in this model by assigning to the class variable, it causes a "stack level too deep".

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def tags=(s)
    self.tags = s.split(/,\s+/)
  end
end
```

Can someone explain why this happens to me? It seems like using `self.tags` causes this virtual attribute to be run until the stack blows up. Which part of ActiveRecord causes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stack level too deep` error has nothing to do with rails. Any basic Ruby class would do this:

```
class Post
  def tags=(s)
    self.tags = s
  end
end

> Post.new.tags = "a,b,c"
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Calling `self.tags =` will just re-execute `tags=(s)` on the same object, over and over again. In your first example, you're directly setting the attribute via `self[:tags] =`, which doesn't re-execute `tags=(s)` at all. I would assume an oversimplification of ActiveRecord is that it does something like your first example for all of a model's fields.